# Suprema of subsets of nonnegative numbers in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a subset of nonnegative numbers in $\mathbb R$. For $n \ge 1$, define
$$E^n :=
\{ x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n: x_k \in E\ \forall\ k\}$$ and 
$$E^{xn} := \{x^n: x \in E\}$$

> (a) What can you say about $\sup E^n$ in terms of $\sup E$ and $\inf E$?
>   (b) What can you say about $\sup E^{xn}$ in terms of $\sup E$ and $\inf E$?

I would like a proof in addition to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $E^{xn}\subseteq E^n$, it’s clear that $\sup E^{xn}\le\sup E^n$. On the other hand, it’s not hard to show that for each $x\in E^{xn}$ there is a $y\in E^n$ such that $x\le y$, so $\sup E^{xn}\le\sup E^n$. Thus, $\sup E^{xn}=\sup E^n$, and you might as well work with $E^n$. Now use the fact that the map $x\mapsto x^n$ is continuous; you may also want to distinguish the cases $\sup E\le 1$ and $\sup E>1$.